# meaning of a complicated paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following paragraph is very confusing to me:

> Much like a work of science, a work of art represents both more and less than a simulacrum of pleasure – it is foregrounded by the values relative to the value-maker, attests to multiple layers of possible meaning, is inevitable only in that it privileges the mores of a particular culture at a particular time in history and, within its shifting temporary context, it is ripe for continual reinterpretation and validation.

The best interpretation I can make is that it means roughly this:

> Similar to a work of science, a work of art looks for a feeling of pleasure, has multiple layers of meaning, represents  particular cultures of particular eras, and is susceptible of continual reinterpretation.

Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: I’ve fleshed out your question a bit more and added some formatting to it. If you disagree with either, you can roll back the edit. If the source of the paragraph (which is indeed pompous, sesquipedalian, horribly worded, and seemingly quite void of any actual content) is available online, you might want to link to it so that people can see more clearly where it’s from.

Comment: This is just way too localized. The answer is unlikely to be of any use to anyone else, and indeed probably won't be of any use even to yourself starting tomorrow. Even more to the point, it boils down to looking up each individual word in a dictionary of your choice. There are no idioms involved or anything. You just look up every word as you go along, and that's the exact meaning.

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to understand something as complicated as the paragraph above, it is useful to know the context. I suspect the paragraph comes from a work of philosophy or of literary criticism, and I suspect that the phrase 'simulacrum of pleasure' is being used in a technical sense. But without knowing the precise work it comes from, there is no way to know exactly what this phrase is intended to mean. However, I will try my best to interpret the paragraph below.

At the start of the paragraph we are asked to consider 3 things: a work of science, a work of art and a simulacrum of pleasure, which I will haphazardly interpret as a representation of pleasure. Note that the 'a' prefacing each of the items indicates that we are talking about any work of art, any work of science and any representation of pleasure.

We are told that works of art and of science represent some things more/better and some things less/worse than representations of pleasure (which, without context, seems a rather obvious statement, so again context is key in understanding what is being said here). What follows is a list of things about works of art which is supposed to justify that works of art represent some things more/better and some things less/worse than representations of pleasure.

We are told a work of art is made to stand out by the value-maker's values (and context is necessary in determining who the value-maker is and what their values are). We are told a work of art attests to multiple layers of meaning (we need context to understand the use of 'attest'; it could mean 'represents', or 'brings about in the mind of the viewer' etc). We are told a work of art privileges the tastes and customs of a particular culture at a particular time in history, and it is only in this sense that a work of art is inevitable (the use of 'inevitable' may well be technical and needs context). Finally we are told that a work of art can be reinterpreted and re-evaluated in a meaningful way at different points of time, because of the different contexts the work has at different points of time.

Comment: A valiant but alas, wasted effort.  It is not possible to elucidate post-modernist prattle.  As Eric Blair pointed out in "Politics and the English Language," this stuff strictly speaking has no discernible meaning in the ordinary sense of the word.